# Elastic Search how to form a SourceBuilder instance from a string. gives named objects are not supported for this parser

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

There is an api which returns a elastic search query with placeholders. Once this query string is obtained I need to update the placeholders and then create a SearchSourceBuilder instance. Using the searchInstance, I need to create a SearchRequest and hit the elastic search instance through restHighLevelClient.

But how do I create the SearchSourceBuilder instance, I have tried this following approach but getting the below error, not sure where, I am going wrong.

```
String queryString = // 
JsonXContentParser xContentParser = new JsonXContentParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, DeprecationHandler.THROW_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, new JsonFactory().createParser(s));
//below line throws the error
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(xContentParser);
searchRequest.source(soruceBuilder)
restHighLevelClient.search(source,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

**Error:**
named objects are not supported for this parser

Comment: The error you get is when creating the JsonXContentParser not the SearchSourceBuilder

Comment: ho, how do, I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is when creating the `JsonXContentParser` not the `SearchSourceBuilder`

Try this:

```
XContentParser xContentParser = XContentType.JSON.xContent()
                .createParser(XContentParserConfiguration.EMPTY, Strings.toString(s));
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(xContentParser);
```

Comment: what is the Strings.toStrings(s)?

Comment: also, I am  using ES version 7.6 on going through the java docs for elasticserach-x-content, I observed that XContentParserConfiguration is introduced in 8.1.2.  I am going ahead and using this jar, I hope it does not throws any problem. It took me sometime to figure out these.

Comment: If you're using 7.6, you should not use JARs from 8.1.2... Just a sec